# Syntax Error PHP 5.3.3 - unexpected '['

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-5.3

How can i correct the following php snippet to run it in php 5.3.3 without parsing error?

Browser Message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

PHP Code Snippet

```
{ public function getDelete($key = NULL) $_DELETE = [];
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_DELETE);
        return NULL !== $key ? self::arrayKey($key, $_DELETE) : $_DELETE;
        }
```

error log message:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: need specific recommendation to use the code snippet in php 5.3.3.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php  You need at least 5.4

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3 doesn't support the `[]` array syntax.  Only PHP 5.4 and later does.

For older PHP, you need to use `array()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: thanks. And in case of this line? $this->getAutoloader()->registerNamespaces([$namespace => $module]);

Comment: @Cash Same issue there. You really should ditch PHP 5.3 though. It's unsupported for a year now - major security issues likely exist in it.

Comment: @Cash `$this->getAutoloader()->registerNamespaces(array($namespace => $module));`